# Why declare a subroutine that returns a subroutine reference in Moose?

Tags: perl, moose

im new to Moose in perl, and i have been reading its documentation when i encountered this one which i dont quite understand:

If you want to use a reference of any sort as the default value, you must return it from a subroutine. **OK i get this statement, and the next example**

```
has 'mapping' => (
      is      => 'ro',
      default => sub { {} },
  );
```

This is necessary because otherwise Perl would instantiate the reference exactly once, and it would be shared by all objects: **This one i dont understand, what does it mean that it would instantiate the reference exactly once and will be shared by all objects? How?**

```
 has 'mapping' => (
      is      => 'ro',
      default => {}, # wrong!
  );
```

Moose will throw an error if you pass a bare non-subroutine reference as the default.

If Moose allowed this then the default mapping attribute could easily end up shared across many objects. Instead, wrap it in a subroutine reference as we saw above. **Dont get this again**

Comment: `{}` isn't a subroutine reference, it's a hash reference.

Answer (score 2):

Because it creates action at a distance, which is bad. Illustration of the problem:

```
package Wrong;
my $default = {};

sub new {
    my ($class) = @_;
    return bless $default => $class;
}

package main;
use 5.010;
my @wobj;
push @wobj, Wrong->new for 0..2;

$wobj[0]->{some_new_attr} = 'foobar';

use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);
print Dumper $wobj[1];  # huh????!
print Dumper $wobj[2];  # that one, too?! why?

say for @wobj;          # ah, it's the same shared address

package Correct;
my $default = sub { return {} };

sub new {
    my ($class) = @_;
    return bless $default->() => $class;
}

package main;
my @cobj;
push @cobj, Correct->new for 0..2;

$cobj[0]->{some_new_attr} = 'foobar';

print Dumper $cobj[$_] for 0..2; # instances 1 and 2 are unaffected

say for @cobj;          # all different addresses
```

Comment: Sorry, no. Between the official documentation, which you quoted at length, and which explains the problem with words, and my answer, which explains with an experiment which you can run and step through with a debugger and examine its output, there's nothing left. It's up to you now to pinpoint exactly which part you cannot understand, and communicate this.